# How I can apply map in this code? (Clojure)

Tags: clojure

I start learn Clojure and need help with task.

I have to write this function:

```
(data-table student-tbl)
;; => ({:surname "Ivanov", :year "1996", :id "1"}
;;     {:surname "Petrov", :year "1996", :id "2"}
;;     {:surname "Sidorov", :year "1997", :id "3"})
```

I must use let, map, next, table-keys and data-record functions.
In this case:

```
student-tbl => (["id" "surname" "year" "group_id"] ["1" "Ivanov" "1998"] ["2" "Petrov" "1997"] ["3" "Sidorov" "1996"])
(table-keys student-tbl) => [:id :surname :year :group_id]
(data-record [:id :surname :year :group_id] ["1" "Ivanov" "1996"]) => {:surname "Ivanov", :year "1996", :id "1"}
```

I wrote this:

```
(defn data-table [tbl]
  (let [[x] (next tbl)]
    (data-record (table-keys tbl) x)
  ))

(data-table student-tbl) => {:surname "Ivanov", :year "1998", :id "1"}
```

How I can use map for right result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is how you should probably write this in practice.  Then I'll show you your mistake so you can learn for your homework.

One way:

```
(defn data-table
  [[headers & data]]
  (let [headers (map keyword headers)
        data-record (partial zipmap headers)]
    (map data-record data)))
```

The key takeaways here are:

- destructure the input to go ahead and separate headers from data
- build the headers once, using the core `keyword` function
- compose a function which always takes the same set of headers, and then map that function over our data
- note that there are no external functions, which is always a nice thing when we can get away with it

Now, to make your way work, what you need to do is map the `data-record` function over x.  First, the `let` binding should bind `(next tbl)` to `x`, not `[x]` (the way you're doing it, you only get the first element of the data set (Ivanov, 1998, 1).

In this example, ignore the `data-record zipmap` and `table-keys` binding in the let. They're there to make this example work, and you can remove them safely.

```
(defn data-table-newb
  [tbl]
  (let [table-keys #(map keyword (first %))
        headers (table-keys tbl)
        data-record zipmap
        x (next tbl)]
    (map #(data-record headers %) x)))
```

Essentially, you compute your table headers at the beginning, then create a new anonymous function that calls `data-record` and gives it your computed headers and an individual vector of data.  You apply that function over every element of your data list, which you have bound to `x`.

Removing the unnecessary functions which are defined elsewhere, you get:

```
(defn data-table-newb
  [tbl]
  (let [headers (table-keys tbl)
        x (next tbl)]
    (map #(data-record headers %) x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, Josh. I understood my mistakes.